# How to specify instruments in AER::ivreg?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

In my regression, I want to instrument a variable pastS with lgrade and run the following code in R:

```r
modiv <- ivreg(servS ~ horS + size + henley + lpd + tri + turn + rail + 
                 enc20 + wheat | pastS | lgrade, data = regdata)
```

I get an error: `length(formula)[2] %in% 1:2 is not TRUE`. Apparently, something is not right with my syntax, but I cannot find an error. Could you help?

Comment: Please make this reproducible, otherwise I get `Error: object 'regdata' not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AER::ivreg` wants you to provide an instrument for each regressor after one separator `|`, so instead of

```
> library(AER)
> ivreg(log(packs) ~ population + tax | log(rprice) | rtdiff, data=c1995)
Error in ivreg(log(packs) ~ population + tax | log(rprice) | rtdiff, data = c1995) : 
  length(formula)[2] %in% 1:2 is not TRUE
```

it's

```
> ivreg(log(packs) ~ log(rprice) + population + tax | rtdiff + population + tax, data=c1995)

Call:
ivreg(formula = log(packs) ~ log(rprice) + population + tax |     rtdiff + population + tax, data = c1995)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  log(rprice)   population          tax  
  7.241e+00   -5.089e-01   -7.907e-09   -4.202e-03
```

You could consider `lfe::felm` instead which is more concise and might fit more to your intuition.

```
> library(lfe)
> felm(log(packs) ~ population + tax | 0 | (log(rprice) ~ rtdiff), data=c1995)
       (Intercept)         population                tax `log(rprice)(fit)` 
         7.241e+00         -7.907e-09         -4.202e-03         -5.089e-01
```

---

*Data:*

```
> data("CigarettesSW", package="AER")
> CigarettesSW <- transform(CigarettesSW,
+                           rprice=price/cpi,
+                           rtdiff=(taxs - tax)/cpi
+ )
> c1995 <- subset(CigarettesSW, year == "1995")
```

Comment: Thank you! I did this both ways, ivreg and felm, and got identical results.